# How can I program a decimal addition with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i program this, the decimal shift needs to be programed that most of it I think , the rest would be just a normal add, any thoughts on how to program this? This is for an incrementer I'm building, the user can press plus or minus and increment a text input.

Comment: so like 3.7 incremented by 1 to 4.7 from within a `input type="text"` or from 3.7 to 3.8?

Comment: yes and the coma needs to be shifted , i have the inputs done, but i dont know how to program the decimal addition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the use of a comma `,` as a decimal separator instead of a `.`.

If there are no other commas used as separators in the number (I don't know what is used for thousand separators in that case), then you could try something like this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/yuEAs/

HTML

```
<input id='one' type='text' value='12,34' /><br>
<input id='two' type='text' value='43,21' /><br>
<input id='result' type='text' /><br>
<div id='click'>Click to add</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#click').click(function() {
       // Replace comma separators with point separators, and parseFloat the result
    var one = parseFloat($('#one').val().replace(',','.'));
    var two = parseFloat($('#two').val().replace(',','.'));
       // Add the numbers
    var result = one + two;
       // Convert the result to a string, and revert the decimal separator back
    $('#result').val( result.toString().replace('.',',') );
});
```

*​I don't have any experience with this, so maybe there's a better way.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

HTML

```
<input id="value" type="text" value="0">
<input id="right" type="button" value="+">
<input id="left" type="button" value="-">
```

JS (with jquery)

```
$("#right").click(function(){
$("#value").val($("#value").val() * 10);
});

$("#left").click(function(){
$("#value").val($("#value").val() / 10);
});
```

Comment: yes but it needs to show like this: 10,00  so you can add 10,25  +  100,10  for example

Comment: it's addition but with comma , i need to show and add monetary values , so theres a need to program the comma shifting

Comment: If you want a button to shift comma to rigth or left, you need just multiply by 10 ou divide by 10. I'll edit my aswser.

Comment: it's not a button, the shift needs to be programed, it's automatical just like in a normal calculator

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. If you sum 3.1 with 10.12, you will have 13.22. You don't need to program comma shift... :(

Comment: @tada your request is very confusing - can you indicate all the input elements + buttons you have and a few sample additions you want to accomplish? (edit this information and add it to the original question)

Comment: @Topera , true, thanks for your help.
@scunliffe, I think i found a solution.
regards.